# Why UAC is prompted when install in done in C:\program files but not C:\?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, installation, windows-installer, uac

Hello, I have signed my application with Verisign, stored all registry variables in HKCU in order not to request for admin right, changed the manifest file but the UAC command still prompts the user whether he/she wants the following to make changes to his/her computer when the application install directory is done in c:\program files (default) . How do I prevent this from happening.

Comment: I believe users are not permitted to write any file in C:\Program Files or  C:\Program Files (x86) without the UAC prompt.

Comment: But this seems to happen every time I start the application which is quite annoying!

Comment: Does your application write any file to C:\Program Files? If not its likely that the problem is your usage of the registry.

Comment: It writes and reads to C:\programdata and HKCU registry only.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to check. First it is the manifest file included in your application,  not the one of your installer. V[S has an option for setting the UAC level](http://inphamousdevelopment.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/requireadmin.jpg) for the application it builds.

Second, you should check if your application, when launched, [is opening any files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from Program Files folder with the **OF_READWRITE** option, this might also triggering the UAC prompt.

Comment: I have done the Manifest settings included in the VS and that seems fine. I have also searched through the application and no **OF_READWRITE** is used anywhere in the application. Most of the application is built around wxWidgets and I believe the access to Programdata (e.g. `wxMkdir(GetProgramDataFolder())` ) file prompts the UAC.

Comment: Strange. You could also spy the system resources to see what is your application trying to access, maybe in that list you can see something that might related to UAC. I use Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) for this, you can set a filter to show you only the resources related to your application process, as by default it is quite verbose.